# tensorflow-gpu not install using anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, anaconda

I try to install tensorflow-gpu in my anaconda base. But it show below errors. I try multiple times but this error not goes.
I install all necessary things like CUDA, CUDNN, Anaconda.
I try to install django that successfully installed but in tensorflow this error showing and not installed.
I not make any conda environment and i wish install tensorflow in base(root) environment.
[image]

Comment: IMO your question is off-topic for SO. In any case, it lacks significant information to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue using reinstalled Anaconda

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly caused by a package version mismatch. Try making a new env with TensorFlow-gpu and Django by using the command:

```
conda create --name YourEnvName tensorFlow-gpu django
```

Then activate the env you just made and continue installing other packages that you need.

If you want to see the reason why it's not properly working, I suggest installing [mamba](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba); it's more performant than vanilla conda and has a faster, more parallelized solver and package installer.